# Send printer commands via socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, printers

i'm trying to send commands to a card printer via socket, but i am unable to make it work. Right now, i have a program developed in php, that is working, but i need to make it work in Java. The program in PHP is something like this:

```
$ESC = chr(27); //Ascii character for Escape
$CR = chr(13); // Ascii character for Carriage Return
$cmd =  $ESC .  $command .  $CR;
socket_send($socket, $cmd, strlen($cmd), 0);
socket_recv($socket, $respuesta, strlen($respuesta), 0);
```

In Java, i am making something like this

```
char ESC = (char)27; //Ascii character for Escape
char CR = (char) 13; //Ascii character for Carriage Return
//////////////
Socket socket = null;
DataInputStream input = null;
DataOutputStream output = null;
// I make another stuff here
socket = new Socket(address,port);
input = new DataInputStream (socket.getInputStream()); 
output  = new DataOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream());
//I make another stuff here
if (socket != null && input != null && output != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    String cmd=ESC+command+CR;
                    byte[] message = cmd.getBytes();              
                    output.writeShort(cmd.length());                                     
                    output.writeBytes(cmd);

                    message = new byte[input.readShort()];                            
                    input.readFully(message);                                                       
                    response = new String(message);

                    salida.close();
                    entrada.close();
                    conec.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());

                }
            }
```

I tried with different type of data: int, UTF-8, long, etc, but doesn't seem to work. I don't know if the printer is expecting more information, or i am sending the wrong type of data

Let me summarize: the code in PHP is working great, but when i am trying to translate that code to Java, and send the commands to the printer via socket, but isn't working at all. I already read the manual, but doesn't help at all

P.D. The brand of the printer is Evolis

P.D. 2 Sorry if i am not explained very well, but english isn't my first language

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know PHP, but do socket_send and socket_recv actually write and read the length of the message to/from the socket before the message itself? Since that is what you're doing with your read/writeShort calls in Java.

Comment: @HeinBlöd According to PHP documentation, socket_send (http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-send.php), sends data to a connected socket, and the return values are the number of bytes sent, or FALSE on error. And socket_recv (http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php), receives data from a connected socket, and the return values are the number of bytes received, or FALSE if there was an error

Yes, i tried other types of data, besides short, but i didn't receive an answer from the device. I don't know if i sent the data wrong, or expecting other type of data

Comment: Can you put the printer in hex trace mode to see what (if anything) is actually arriving?

Comment: Aren't writeShort and readShort superfluous in your Java code then ...? The message length apparently is not part of the printer network protocol?

Comment: @Duston How can i put the printer in hex trace mode?

Comment: @HeinBlöd Well, the manual don't explain the part, it only says that the character Escape must be first, then must be followed for the command, and then the character (;), separating the different parameters, and finished for the character Carriage Return. I don't know if the message length is a parameter that must be received for the printer itself; in the PHP code, the function socket_send has this four parameters: socket, buffer, length in bytes of data to be sent, and flags. Seems that is part of the information that must be receive

Comment: The programming guide, if anyone is interested to check

http://www.plastikkartendrucker.at/support/allgemein/Programming_Guide.pdf

Comment: So did you already try it without the write/readShort statements? There's no mention of the message length in the communication protocol in the programming guide.

Comment: See why i am so confused @HeinBlöd ? In the example in PHP, the length of the message is used as parameter; and if you see the example in C++, you will be more confused. Right now, i tried with the write() and read () methods, without any response. Yes, writeShort() and readShort() was one of the first options; even i tried it at this moment, without any positive answer.

Comment: Tried PrintWriter without any answer. Anyone knows how the php function socket_send works? Perhaps, the device is waiting the parameters in certain order, and maybe, the function socket_send is doing internally; and if that is true, probably we can find an option to concatenate the parameters and send it to the device, via socket

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution. Let me share it with you

```
char ESC = (char)27; //Ascii character for ESCAPE
char CR = (char) 13; //Ascii character for Carriage Return
/////////////
Socket socket = null;
OutputStream output= null;
BufferedReader reader= null;
///////////
try
            { 
                socket = new Socket(address,port);
                socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                output = socket.getOutputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) {etc... }
/////////
if (socket != null  && output != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    String cmd=ESC+command+CR;
                    output.write(cmd.getBytes());
                    output.flush();
                    socket.shutdownOutput();

                    response = reader.readLine();

                     System.out.println(response.toString());

                    output.close();
                    socket.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());

                }
            }
```

The key in this solution was the method **socket.shutdownOutput();**, because i think that the device is unable to send and receive data at the same time, so if you want a response from the device, you must close the output first (the manual doesn't help at all, so i am guessing right now)

Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: would you mind sharing your php code? For a project in the near future i am planning to use an evolis printer to print some event badges (with QRcode/barcode). I have a database with visitors and would like to give them a personal badge with holds vcard data or a unique key to their database data. So each exhibitor can get their data someting in the line of that

Comment: I am getting "response" = null in my case